# Windows Remote Desktop to a computer which is using multiple screens?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

Generally, people ask about how to use multiple monitors in Windows Remote Desktop. However, I need to connect to a computer which is using multiple monitors (two, in this case).

I mean, when I get connected, I can see only a half of the screen. What can I do about?

Comment: what version of windows are you using on both the machines? I understand that multiple-monitors support in Windows 7's Remote Desktop is available only on Windows 7 Ultimate and Windows 7 Enterprise. (It is also available in Windows Server 2008 R2.)

Comment: Both Windows 7. Do you mean [this option](http://i.imgur.com/rISJkmk.png)? Because I think that isn't what I need.

Comment: I'm unable to look at the picture right now (my office blocks that content). See if this link is helpful. http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/use-multiple-monitors-with-windows-7s-remote-desktop-connection/ and this https://support.steadfast.net/Knowledgebase/Article/View/107/0/using-multiple-monitors-with-windows-remote-desktop

Comment: Thanks but I need the opposite! I'm willing to connect to a computer which is actually using two monitors. I need to fit those into my remote local session. I can only see half of the screen now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Scale Content" is what you're looking for, or its translation. I don't see it on the image you posted & I'm on Mac so my prefs look completely different. On mine it's directly above the 'Use all monitors' option.

Ah - research tells me that option isn't directly available until Windows 8.1 & also that on Windows it's called 'Smart Sizing'.

To use Smart Sizing in Windows XP or Windows 7 you need to edit your .rdp files with notepad and type in the following line:

`smart sizing:i:1`

Comment: really? why not including that on the UI? I'll try that!

Comment: Wish you luck :)

Answer (score 1):

When you connect, you don’t see half the screen. In fact, this is impossible—because, unlike VNC, RDP doesn’t connect to the console (“physical”) session but creates a new virtual screen. Its size is set when connecting ([starting with Windows 8.1, it’s fully dynamic](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2013/12/16/resolution-and-scaling-level-updates-in-rdp-8-1.aspx)). Usually, windows get rearranged so none remain off-screen.

RDP offers two multi-monitor modes, both of which require a sufficiently large client display.

- `/span`: Creates a single large window. Doesn’t offer multi-monitor features remotely (appears as one display) but is compatible with all Windows versions
- “Use all my monitors”: Forwards client display’s information to the RDP server and creates virtual screens accordingly. Offers real multi-monitor experience, but requires specific Windows editions.

`smart sizing:i:1` can, combined with a large virtual resolution (has to be set in the config file, too), offer an environment somewhat like `/span`. However, you won’t have multi-monitor features. You also won’t be able to zoom in our out.